# Model Binding is forcing to have value in non-required field while posting the form in .NET Core MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am posting value from MVC View.. Below Is .cshtml Code

```
 <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContractStartDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContractStartDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContractStartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContractEndDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContractEndDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContractEndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsActive" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Website" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Website" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Website" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LogoUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LogoUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LogoUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

*This is my Model Code*

```
public class Client : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Client Name is Required")]
        [Display(Name ="Client Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contract StartDate is Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date Format")]
        [Display(Name = "Contract StartDate")]
        public DateTime ContractStartDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contract EndDate is Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date Format")]
        [Display(Name = "Contract End Date")]
        public DateTime ContractEndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Is Active")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Website { get; set; }

        public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

BaseEntity.cs Code

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedIPAddress { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedIPAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

This is Post function in MVC Controller..

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,ContractStartDate,ContractEndDate,IsActive,Website,LogoUrl")] Client client)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(client);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(client);
        }
```

When I click on submit button after providing required values...  it shows validation error even for non-required filed of BaseEntity.cs class.

[image]

When I fill all these non-required field and remove from post Bind[] method of controller... There it is showing Model is invalid.

[image]

Controller Model Validation

[image]

See Detailed error...

[image]

Please help.... how to bypass this error.

Comment: You shouldn't be using your EF entities as models in your front end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using net 6 you have 2 choices

1. Remove or comment this line in EF core project

```
 <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
```

2. Or manually make each property of each class nullable

```
       public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string? CreatedIPAddress { get; set; }
      // ---and so on for all classes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(opt => opt.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

This will Suppress Implicit Required Attribute For NonNullable Reference Types

Comment: For WebAPI Use : 
builder.Services.AddControllers(x =>
{
    x.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;
});